# Get the next ID in Access database(now the ID is M15, i want get M16)

Tags: java

My Access Database memberID now is M15 , i want to get the next memberID M16 , how to get it and display in a text field ?

String query;

```
query = "INSERT INTO Membership VALUES ('" +memberID_a.getText() + "','" +memberName_a.getText() + "','" + icNo_a.getText()  + "','" + gender_a.getText()  +"','" + birthday_a.getText()  +"','" + telephoneNo_a.getText()  + "','" + mobileNo_a.getText()  + "','" + email_a.getText()  + "','" + address_a.getText()  + "','" + postalCode_a.getText() + "','" + state_a.getText()  + "','" + country_a.getText()  + "','" + memberPoint_a.getText() + "');"; 



try{

        stmtInsert = conn.createStatement(); 
        stmtInsert.executeUpdate(query);

} catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR"+ex.toString(),"ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: The question is very unclear. You are doing insert operation, you are supposed to do select?

Answer (score 0):

```
query = "INSERT INTO Membership VALUES ('" +memberID_a.getText() + "','" +memberName_a.getText() + "','" + icNo_a.getText()  + "','" + gender_a.getText()  +"','" + birthday_a.getText()  +"','" + telephoneNo_a.getText()  + "','" + mobileNo_a.getText()  + "','" + email_a.getText()  + "','" + address_a.getText()  + "','" + postalCode_a.getText() + "','" + state_a.getText()  + "','" + country_a.getText()  + "','" + memberPoint_a.getText() + "');";
```

NEVER, EVER do that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

instead use

```
query = "INSERT INTO Membership VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Where each ? is a placeholder.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Anyway, the important thing to realise about database tables is that the order of the rows is meaningless unless you use an 'order by' clause in your query. So if you want to order by the id column,  use

```
SELECT * from Membership ORDER BY id;
```